# How do I change the format options for shell-format VS code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, format

I have recently started using VS Code, and it doesn't seem to have an inbuilt shell script formatter. So I got this one [shell-format](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=foxundermoon.shell-format) but I cannot find a way to change how it formats scripts. How do I change its format options?

Answer (score 0):

I used shell-format to change the tab size. the default was 4, but I'd like 3 (kind wierd, yah?)

So I modified settings.json

```
"[shellscript]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 3,
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "foxundermoon.shell-format"
    }
```

I only added the "tabSize". The rest came from the installation.

It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the vs code setting for that extension, and follow the instructions. i.e. you can set the flags for customization.

Comment: Hi @nkk, for me, under "Extension Settings" it just says "No Settings Found" for this extension. Can you elaborate on where you set the flags? Is it possible to do in the latest version (Version: 1.67.0 (Universal))? Thanks.